# How can I avoid empty values on IE.Navigate and GetElementById?

Tags: excel, vba, getelementsbyclassname, is-empty

I code some vba scritp that open ie.navigate and get some values from webpage into excell values.

But sometimes that url does not load propetly on webpage and the values are not filled. So when the getelement try get any valume my loop camer fatal error and stoped.

another point is, imagine the all page is loadade..but for this criteria some geElementID is empyt...what I can do to avoid it.

my code here:

```js
Sub Extract_One_Airport()
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
Dim dtStart As Date
Datec = 0
CountRange = 1
For lSCtr = 0 To 5

       Set P1 = Sheets("Inicio").Range("A9") 'Primeira p do link
                    Set P2 = Sheets("Inicio").Range("A10") 'Origem
              link = P1 & P2
                    
                    IE.navigate link
                    IE.Visible = True
                 
                    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:45")) ' For internal page refresh or loading
                    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
                    Set doc = IE.document
                    Dim dd As Variant
                  
                    dd = doc.getElementsByClassName("valuefortoday")(0).innerText
                  
                    Sheets("Resul").Range("C" & CountRange).Value = dd
                    Count = Count + 1
                    CountRange = CountRange + 1
              
            Next
        
End Sub
```

As I said..sometimes the **getElementsByClassName("valuefortoday")(0).innerText** cames empty, cause the site there no information for this day...how can I avoid empty values and skip it for the next day?

Answer (score 0):

This write the clipboard to StdOut. As you can only use IE's clipboard in the intranet zone without security dialogs, I navigate to a local file and wait for it to finish loading.

You can also do it with events.

```
Sub Clip
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
    ie.Visible = 0
    ie.Navigate2 FilterPath & "Filter.html"
    Do 
        wscript.sleep 100
    Loop until ie.document.readystate = "complete"  
    txt=ie.document.parentwindow.clipboardData.GetData("TEXT")
    ie.quit
    If IsNull(txt) = true then 
        outp.writeline "No text on clipboard"
    else
        outp.writeline txt
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `lenght` property of `valueForToday`. If there is no such element then lenght will be equal to zero.

```
IE.navigate link

' wait until the page is fully loaded
Do Until IE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

IE.Visible = True

Dim valueForToday
Set valueForToday = doc.getElementsByClassName("valuefortoday")

If valueForToday.Length > 0 Then
    ' element exists, get its inner text
    dd = valueForToday(0).innerText
    Sheets("Resul").Range("C" & CountRange).Value = dd
    Count = Count + 1
    CountRange = CountRange + 1
End If
```